# JAVA - Number triangle with for loops

Tags: java

so I know there are a lot of number pyramid questions on here but I looked through several and couldn't figure out my question.

I need to make my triangle look like this...

```
                1
              1 2 1
            1 2 3 2 1 
          1 2 3 4 3 2 1 
        1 2 3 4 5 4 3 2 1 
      1 2 3 4 5 6 5 4 3 2 1 
    1 2 3 4 5 6 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 
  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1
```

After a lot of trial and error and using a python code I had for a similar project I got it done but the numbers are in a different order.  I think maybe I don't fully understand exactly how the code is working piece by piece or I'd probably be able to figure it out.  However, this is what I have.

```
                        1  
                     2  1  2  
                  3  2  1  2  3  
               4  3  2  1  2  3  4  
            5  4  3  2  1  2  3  4  5  
         6  5  4  3  2  1  2  3  4  5  6  
      7  6  5  4  3  2  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  
   8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  
9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
```

Here is my code.  Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 9; i++) {
    for (int j = 9; j > i; j--) {
        System.out.print("   ");
    }
    for (int j = i; j > 1; j--) {
        System.out.print(j + "  ");
    }
    for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
        System.out.print(j + "  ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Thanks again for any help!!

Scott

Comment: please tell me it's not for oDesk

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like the following code:

```
/* Define the maximum number of lines */
    int maxLines = 9;
    /* Loop through from 1 to the maximum number of lines */
    for(int lineNumber = 1; lineNumber <= maxLines; lineNumber++) {

        /* Create the LHS spacing */
        for(int linePosition = 0; linePosition < maxLines - lineNumber; linePosition++)
            System.out.print("\t");

        /* Print the LHS numbers */
        for(int number = 1; number <= lineNumber; number++)
            System.out.print(number + "\t");

        /* Print the RHS numbers */
        for(int number = lineNumber - 1; number > 0; number--)
            System.out.print(number + "\t");

        /* Create the RHS spacing */
        for(int linePosition = 0; linePosition < maxLines - lineNumber; linePosition++)
            System.out.print("\t");

        /* Create a new line */
        System.out.println();
    }
```

Running that gave me the output you desire:

```
                                1                                   
                            1   2   1                               
                        1   2   3   2   1                           
                    1   2   3   4   3   2   1                       
                1   2   3   4   5   4   3   2   1                   
            1   2   3   4   5   6   5   4   3   2   1               
        1   2   3   4   5   6   7   6   5   4   3   2   1           
    1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   7   6   5   4   3   2   1       
1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   8   7   6   5   4   3   2   1
```

*-Thomas*

Comment: Wow you're awesome Thomas!  Thanks for naming the variables like that so I can more easily understand how it works.  One question though, what does the "\t" do?

Comment: "\t" is a tab character. Much like "\n" is a new-line character. I used it to get a uniform separation between the numbers. Though using spaces works just as well! :)

Answer (score 0):

In your second internal for loop, replace this:

```
for (int j = i; j > 1; j--) {
    System.out.print(j + "  ");
}
```

With this:

```
 for (int j = 1; j < i; j++) {
        System.out.print(j + "  ");
    }
```

Comment: That worked on the left half of the triangle but not on the right.

Answer (score 0):

Use below code.

```
    int startnum=1, endnum = 9;
    for (int i = startnum; i <= endnum; i++) 
    {
        for (int j = endnum; j > i; j--) {
            System.out.print("   ");
        }
        for (int j = startnum; j <= i; j++) {
            System.out.print(j + "  ");
        }
        for (int j = i -1 ; j > 0; j--) {
            System.out.print(j + "  ");
        }

        for (int j = startnum -1; j < endnum - i; j++) {
            System.out.print("   ");
        }

        System.out.println();
    }
```

**Output:**

```
                        1                          
                     1  2  1                       
                  1  2  3  2  1                    
               1  2  3  4  3  2  1                 
            1  2  3  4  5  4  3  2  1              
         1  2  3  4  5  6  5  4  3  2  1           
      1  2  3  4  5  6  7  6  5  4  3  2  1        
   1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1     
1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1
```

Comment: Thank you Nishanthi but that is the same as above, the left half is correct but the right half remained the same.

Comment: @user3862586: I didnt notice that. Wait while i correct it.

Answer (score 0):

for any pattern identify the right triangles present this ha 3 right traingles so 3 loops inside the main loop.

package com.test;

public class stackanswers {

```
public static void main(String arg[]) {

    int N = 9;
    for(int i = 1 ; i<=N; i++) {

        for(int j = 1;j<=N-i;j++) {
            System.out.print(" ");
        }

        for(int k = 1 ; k<=i;k++) {
            System.out.print(k);
        }

        for(int j = i-1 ; j>=1; j--) {
            System.out.print(j);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

}